# Nelmio API doc bundle post request with boolean always returns true

Tags: rest, fosrestbundle, symfony4, nelmioapidocbundle

I'm developping a Symfony 4 API REST app with Nelmio Api Doc Bundle v3.

I am sending this request :

```
curl -X POST "http://dev.api_events.jessie/api/event-types" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ZmU1MTgxNzNkZjM5ZTU2NzdiODVkODgxMmE2ZmE2OWUyMjY1ZWIxYzgxMjdlOTA3NjBiODM5Yzg1NTEzNjFlYw" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "fullName=aaaaaaaaaaa&shortName=aaaaaaaaaaa&dns=aaaaaaaaaa**&mandatoryRegistration=false"**
```

This is the response body :

```
{
  "id": 19,
  "full_name": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
  "short_name": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
  "dns": "aaaaaaaaaa",
  **"mandatory_registration": true,**
  "places": [],
  "participation_types": []
}
```

I have absolutely no idea why i send mandatoryRegistration=false and my response have "mandatory_registration": true.

I paste my Controller, Form, Entity code below. And the nelmio api doc and fos_rest configuration code.

Controller :

```
 /**
 * Creates a new eventType entity.
 *
 * @Route("/event-types", methods="POST")
 * @Operation(
 *     tags={"event_type"},
 *     summary="Creates a new event type entity",
 *     consumes={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="Authorization",
 *         in="header",
 *         description="Bearer",
 *         required=true,
 *         type="string"
 *     ),
 *    @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="fullName",
 *         in="formData",
 *         description="event type full name",
 *         required=true,
 *         type="string"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="shortName",
 *         in="formData",
 *         description="event name",
 *         required=true,
 *         type="string"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="dns",
 *         in="formData",
 *         description="event type dns",
 *         required=true,
 *         type="string"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="mandatoryRegistration",
 *         in="formData",
 *         description="is the registration mandatory?",
 *         required=true,
 *         type="boolean"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response=Response::HTTP_CREATED,
 *         description="Event Type created",
 *        @Model(type=EventType::class, groups={"event_type"})
 *     )
 * )
 *
 */
public function postEventTypeAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $event_type = new EventType();
    $form = $this->createForm(EventTypeType::class, $event_type);
    $form->submit($request->request->all()); // Validation des données


    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($event_type);
        $em->flush();

        return View::create($event_type, Response::HTTP_CREATED , []);
    }
    else{
        return View::create($form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST , []);
    }

}
```

EventType form :

```
class EventTypeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fullName'
        )
                ->add('shortName')
                ->add('dns')
                ->add('mandatoryRegistration')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => EventType::class
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'event_type';
    }
}
```

EventType entity :

```
class EventType
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Groups({"event_type","place"})
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="full_name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Groups({"event_type","place","event_type_form_data"})
 */
private $fullName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Groups({"event_type","place","event_type_form_data"})
 */
private $shortName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dns", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Groups({"event_type","event_type_form_data"})
 */
private $dns;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mandatory_registration", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 * 
 * @Groups({"event_type","event_type_form_data"})
 */
private $mandatoryRegistration;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Place", mappedBy="eventType", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $places;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EventTypeParticipationType", mappedBy="eventType", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $participationTypes;
```

Config :

```
nelmio_api_doc:
documentation:
    info:
        title: Api Events
        description: L4M Admin Events access point.
        version: 1.0.0
    security_definitions:
        api_key:
            type: apiKey
            name: authorization
            in: header
    security: 
        api_key: []
    sandbox:
        request_format:
            method: accept_header
        accept_type: application/json
        body_format: 
            formats: [ form, json ]             # array of enabled body formats,
                                            # remove all elements to disable the selectbox
            default_format: form         

areas: # to filter documented routes
    path_patterns:
        - ^/api(?!/doc$) # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc
        - ^/oauth/v2/token

fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener:  true
    body_listener: true
    #allowed_methods_listener:  true
    routing_loader: true
    view:
        view_response_listener:  true
        formats:
            json: true

# exception:
#     codes:
#         App\Exception\MyException: 403
#     messages:
#         App\Exception\MyException: Forbidden area.

format_listener:
    enabled: true
    rules:
        - { path: ^/, prefer_extension: false, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ json, xml, html ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some debug and find out i was trying to put a string in a boolean field which always returns true ...

Here's my solution : do not send "false" in the request, instead send 0 or 1 :

Controller edit :

```
 /* @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="mandatoryRegistration",
 *         in="formData",
 *         description="is the registration mandatory?",
 *         required=true,
 *         type="integer",
 *         enum={0,1}
 *     ),
```